# Reasons why a page might not load (no matter how long you wait) when using Selenium

Tags: python, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, webautomation

I'm using Selenium with Chrome and Python, trying to scrape some data from a website. The website you have to interact with, so some elements are not available until certain options have been selected; I think I have heard this referred to as "conditional load."

The issue is this: I select a certain option from the webpage in the script and wait for the next element in the process to become available, which happens usually after the website processes for 2 - 10 seconds. But when running this script, it doesn't gives me the next element--it will sit and load forever.

When I look into troubleshooting Selenium and waiting, it usually has to do with how to tell Selenium to wait for something to become available, but that is not my issue. My issue is the element I need becomes available when interacting with the site manually, and not when using Selenium. I don't know how to troubleshoot this.

It's not that it *never* worked...it actually did a handful of times. My perception is the website somehow knows it is not a person interacting. But my script does not go very fast, and like I said it has worked before, but after more than 2 or 3 tries it never works again. I've tried switching my VPN (this actually did work once but never again).

For a little more detail if needed: this is a money sending website. When you input the amount of money you want to send, the website goes to the next step (i.e. there are no buttons pressed to signal this action--just inserting the value for the money you want to send is what does it). Usually in the process the next step is to choose the method for the receiver to pick up the money. This is where it gets stuck.
The method I am using to insert the amount of money to send is `send_keys()` which I then insert a string of 100--for $100. This is enough to trigger the next phase of the process sometimes.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.